# How to append new elemnt to XML-file using php DOMdocument?

Tags: php, xml, dom, domdocument

I have this test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Images>
  <Image>
    <Id>765</Id>
    <Title>Img title 1</Title>
    <Name>some_path_to_img.jpg</Name>
  </Image>
</Images>
```

I try to append new `'<Image>'` to `'<Images>'`, but without success.
Here is my code:

```
function update_xml_file() {
  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
  $xml->formatOutput = true;

  $base_node = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Images')->item(0);
  $newimage = $xml->createElement("Image");

  $img_id = $xml->createElement("Id");
  $img_title = $xml->createElement("Title");
  $img_name = $xml->createElement("Name");

  $img_id->nodeValue = '766';
  $img_title->nodeValue = 'Image title 2';
  $img_name->nodeValue = 'some_path_to_img2.jpg';

  $newimage->appendChild($img_id);
  $newimage->appendChild($img_title);
  $newimage->appendChild($img_name);

  $base_node->appendChild($newimage);

  umask();
  $xml->save("test.xml");
}
```

Looking around for related discussions didn't help me.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little typo in the code which loads the xml data.

Change it to:

```
$xml->loadXML(file_get_contents('test.xml'));
```

or ( better)

```
$xml->load('test.xml');
```

Refer to the documentation of [`DOMDocument::loadXML()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) and [`DOMDocument::load()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this package from github to make it simple http://github.com/toureiliass/xdt

You can do it in a few line of code

```
$con = new XDT();
$con->connect('test.xml');
$con->getDocumentRootElement()->append('<image><id>765</id><title>some title</title><name>some_path_to_image.jpg</name></image>');
$con->save();
```